# How does Xcode store "project info" and "file info"

Tags: xcode

I need to know how Xcode stores the stuff that comes up when you press the blue "info" button.  Is there a text file somewhere or anything like that?

Thanks

Comment: Why not take a look at it? In Finder right-click on the `.xcodeproj` and choose *"Show package contents"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect that it's all in the 3 files hidden inside the *.xcodeproj package.  I think they're XML.

Comment: Well, the <username>.mode1v3 file is XML, but the others aren't.